# Using Timer In WCF Or ASMX based webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, asmx

i have a scenario, i want to monitor database(SQL Server) table, if record is inserted in it my webservice should through a message to moblie phone.

i have written function of throwing message to mobile phone already, but i dont know how to use timer to hit database after few intervals to monitor that table using web service.

any one help me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are going to poll a database endlessly looking for a record on a mobile device. You are going to kill your battery and any user will delete the app within one day of installing it.

Comment: Don't do polling. Put a trigger on the table(s) you want to monitor and use SQLServer service broker for managing a queue to which you can subscribe in your WCF service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you want webservice,  a windows service or app running through windows scheduler would be better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get the question but sound pretty straight forward to me.
In the startup code of your WCF service you start a System.Timers.Timer. In the timer tick event you call a StoredProc or something that reads the currently available records in the DB and returns them to the service. There you process them and then delete the records in the DB (or mark them as processed).